# Access SQL query without duplicate results

Tags: sql, ms-access

I made a query and wanted to not have any duplicates but i got some times 3 duplicates and when i used DISTINCT or DISTINCTROW i got only 2 duplicates.

```
SELECT f.flight_code, 
       f.status, 
       a.airport_name, 
       a1.airport_name, 
       f.departing_date+f.departing_time AS SupposedDepartingTime,  
       f.landing_date+f.landing_time AS SupposedLandingTime, 
       de.actual_takeoff_date+de.actual_takeoff_time AS ActualDepartingTime,  
       SupposedLandingTime+(ActualDepartingTime-SupposedDepartingTime) AS ActualLandingTime
FROM 
(((Flights AS f 
   LEFT JOIN Aireports AS a 
      ON a.airport_code = f.depart_ap) 
   LEFT JOIN Aireports AS a1 
      ON f.target_ap = a1.airport_code)
   LEFT JOIN Irregular_Events AS ie 
      ON f.flight_code = ie.flight_code)
   LEFT JOIN Delay_Event AS de 
      ON ie.IE_code = de.delay_code;
```

had to use LEFT JOIN because when i used INNER JOIN i missed some of the things i wanted to show because i wanted to see all the flights and not only the flights that got delayed or canceled.

This is the results when i used INNER JOIN, you can see only the flights that have the status "ביטול" or "עיכוב" and that is not what i wanted.

[the results with LEFT JOIN][2]
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgE2G.png
and when i used DISTINCT where you see the rows with the NUMBER 6 on the first column it appear  only two times

**IMPORTANT!**
I just checked my query and all the tables i use there and i saw my problem but dont know how to fix it!
in the table `Irregular_Events` i have more the one event for flights 3,6 and 8 and that is why when i use LEFT JOIN i see more even thou i use distinct, please give me some help!

Comment: Use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2):

Not entirely sure without seeing the table structure, but this might work:

```
SELECT f.flight_code, 
       f.status, 
       a.airport_name, 
       a1.airport_name, 
       f.departing_date+f.departing_time AS SupposedDepartingTime,  
       f.landing_date+f.landing_time AS SupposedLandingTime, 
       de.actual_takeoff_date+de.actual_takeoff_time AS ActualDepartingTime,  
       SupposedLandingTime+(ActualDepartingTime-SupposedDepartingTime) AS ActualLandingTime
FROM 
((Flights AS f 
   LEFT JOIN Aireports AS a 
      ON a.airport_code = f.depart_ap) 
   LEFT JOIN Aireports AS a1 
      ON f.target_ap = a1.airport_code)
   LEFT JOIN 
   (
   SELECT 
   ie.flight_code,
   de1.actual_takeoff_date,
   de1.actual_takeoff_time
   FROM
   Irregular_Events ie
   INNER JOIN Event AS de1
      ON ie.IE_code = de1.delay_code
   ) AS de
      ON f.flight_code = de.flight_code
```

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to tell what is the problem with your query without any sample of the output, and without any description of the structure of your tables.

But your problem is that your are querying from the `flights` table, which [I assume] can be linked to multiple `irregular_events`, which can possibly also be linked to multiple `delay_event`.

If you want to get only one row per flight, you need to make sure your joins return only one row too. Maybe you can do it by adding one more condition to the join, or by adding a condition in a sub-query.

**EDIT**

You could try to add a `GROUP BY` to the query:

```
   GROUP BY 
      f.flight_code, 
      f.status, 
      a.airport_name, 
      a1.airport_name;
```

Comment: flights can be linked to multiple `irregular_events` but `irregular_events` can be linked to one `delay_event` each.
by using the `irregular_events` and the `delay_event` i can know if a flight is canceled or just delayed and then i can show the actual takeoff and landing time of each flight.
but if i used INNER JOIN i only see the  delayed and canceled flights and that is not what i wanted so i used LEFT JOIN and then i got in some places 3 duplicates